# Proof that the collection of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Just looking for some feedback on my proof. Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Suppose $A$ is the collection of all finite sets in $\mathbb{N}$. Trivially we have $\emptyset = 1$. Define function f on A as follows: 
      \begin{equation*}
        f(A) = p_{a_1} p_{a_2} \dots p_{a_n} \text{ if } A_i = \{a_1, a_2, \dots, n\}      
      \end{equation*}
      Where $p_{a_i}$ are distinct primes and $f(A) \subset \mathbb{N}$. Thus the collection of all finite sets in $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Comment: What are $p_{a_{1}}, \ldots, p_{a_{n}}$? Are you fixing a particular enumeration of the primes?

Comment: Correct p is prime

Comment: That's pretty cute.  Allow for f(empty set) = 1.  Explicitly point out that the p_a's are distinct primes and it wouldn't hurt to point out that the prime products are distinct and thus f(A) is a subset of N.  But yes, the proof is good and clever.

Comment: @copper.hat: that function certainly isn't injective, as $\{1, 4\}$ and $\{2, 3\}$ give the same power of $p$ (if this is for a single prime $p$). If one fixes an enumeration of the primes, then $f$ defined above is an injection. Apologies if I've misunderstood your comment.

Comment: I assumed he did not mean that at all.  I assumed he meant if a_i = m then p_a_i = p_m, the mth prime.  Thus as the subsets A are distinct the f(A)s are each numbers with distinct prime factors and thus unique so collection of all f(A)s is a subset of N.  If he had meant p_a_i = p^a_i for a single prime p, the proof wouldn't work in the least bit.

Comment: I presumed that was the intent, but misunderstood the notation.

Comment: @AlexWertheim the primes are distinct, indexed by the values of sets.

Comment: @fleablood thanks for the tips, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @fleablood I've updated my proof to reflect your comments.